# How to resolve java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError errors in flutter?

Tags: flutter

When I run the app from flutter to the Android simulator, the following error is returned, and it does not run, I don't know what the problem is, please advise on the error.

```
    Launching lib/main.dart on Android SDK built for arm64 in debug mode...
lib/main.dart:1
✓  Built build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-debug.apk.
Connecting to VM Service at ws://127.0.0.1:57149/NUW2Tq4P_Hg=/ws
E/AndroidRuntime( 8510): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime( 8510): Process: com.example.qnsdk_example, PID: 8510
E/AndroidRuntime( 8510): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroidx/localbroadcastmanager/content/LocalBroadcastManager;
E/AndroidRuntime( 8510):    at com.yolanda.health.qnblesdk.out.QNBleApi.setBleDeviceDiscoveryListener(QNBleApi.java:787)
E/AndroidRuntime( 8510):    at com.example.qnsdk.QNSdkPlugin.setBleDeviceDiscoveryListener(QNSdkPlugin.kt:146)
E/AndroidRuntime( 8510):    at com.example.qnsdk.QNSdkPlugin.onMethodCall(QNSdkPlugin.kt:82)
E/AndroidRuntime( 8510):    at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:262)
E/AndroidRuntime( 8510):    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.invokeHandler(DartMessenger.java:178)
E/AndroidRuntime( 8510):    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.lambda$handleMessageFromDart$0$DartMessenger(DartMessenger.java:206)
E/AndroidRuntime( 8510):    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.-$$Lambda$DartMessenger$R4HPk6oFVb-i-YR_PN9YE6kqx1I.run(Unknown Source:12)
E/AndroidRuntime( 8510):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
E/AndroidRuntime( 8510):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
E/AndroidRuntime( 8510):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
E/AndroidRuntime( 8510):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
E/AndroidRuntime( 8510):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 8510):    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
E/AndroidRuntime( 8510):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
E/AndroidRuntime( 8510): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "androidx.localbroadcastmanager.content.LocalBroadcastManager" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.qnsdk_example-cDdo9nfJTxqNGC_B2Gxa2g==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.qnsdk_example-cDdo9nfJTxqNGC_B2Gxa2g==/lib/arm64, /data/app/com.example.qnsdk_example-cDdo9nfJTxqNGC_B2Gxa2g==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /system/product/lib64]]
E/AndroidRuntime( 8510):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:196)
E/AndroidRuntime( 8510):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
E/AndroidRuntime( 8510):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
E/AndroidRuntime( 8510):    ... 14 more
I/flutter ( 8510): initSDK 1108
I/Process ( 8510): Sending signal. PID: 8510 SIG: 9
Lost connection to device.
Exited (sigterm)
```

and in the sdk manager

android sdk command-line tools (latest)

I followed it because I had to check it, but the error does not go away and continues.

[image]

Comment: Try to disable instant run if you are on mac Android Studio --> Preferences --> Build, Execution, Deployment --> Instant Run.
or if you are in window Android Studio --> File --> Setting --> Build, execution, deploy --> Instant run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Open Tools > SDK Manager
choose Appearance & Behavior > System Settings > Android SDK
Select SDK Tools 
Check Android SDK Command-line tools and click ‘apply’.
```

Comment: Thank you for answer!! But the problem is not solved, I edited the post, please see.

Comment: It has already installed or you applied it? Android SDK only works with JDK 8 ,check your version of SDK and upgrade it.